# pushing an object to an array in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to send an object to an array in my model, but every time I do, the array is still empty.

I pass the object to the backend and it arrives here:

```
var addFavoriteRecipe = function(req, res){
    if(req.user){
        console.log(req.body);
        userModel.User.find({_id: req.user._id}, {$push :{favoriteRecipes: {name: req.body.alias, _id: req.body._id}}}, function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send("success!");
            }
        });
    }else{
        var sendBackError = {err: true, message: "You are not logged in."}
        res.send(sendBackError);
    }
}
```

The console log on `req.body` shows all the data I passed back, and has the two fields I'm trying to push into the array.

Here is my Model:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
      type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  friendsList: {
    type: Array,
  },
  favoriteRecipes: {
    type: Array,
  }
});
```

I've toyed around with the code, but I really am lost as to where I should go from here. I want to think it's something on my model, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your model for an array of objects, either this way:

```
favoriteRecipes: [{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: String
}]
```

or

```
favoriteRecipes: { type : Array , "default" : [] }
```

but, The problem seems to be here:

```
 userModel.User.find(
   {_id: req.user._id}, 
   { $push : {favoriteRecipes: {name: req.body.alias, _id: req.body._id}}},
   function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send("success!");
            }
 });
```

You are using `find` you need to change it to `update`:

```
 userModel.User.update(
     {_id: req.user._id}, 
     { $push : { favoriteRecipes: {name: req.body.alias, _id: req.body._id}}},
     function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }else{
                res.send("success!");
            }
 });
```