# Node.js - how to inspect request data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, curl

I have a Node.js route that sends back some text and logs the request:

```
app.post('/registerUser', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World post!')
  console.log(req);
})
```

Then I hit that route with curl, like so:

`curl --data "username==test&foo==bar" http://localhost:3000/registerUser`

And that's what I'm getting out via node:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 183,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 3,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 222,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 144720,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: 17,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 17\r\nETag: W/"11-5i2g3OJs8No9M8PUhnLubxYJmZY"\r\nDate: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:06:49 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        statusCode: 200 } },
  connection:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 183,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 3,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 222,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 144720,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: 17,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 17\r\nETag: W/"11-5i2g3OJs8No9M8PUhnLubxYJmZY"\r\nDate: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:06:49 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        statusCode: 200 } },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers:
   { host: 'localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'curl/7.43.0',
     accept: '*/*',
     'content-length': '23',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'Host',
     'localhost:3000',
     'User-Agent',
     'curl/7.43.0',
     'Accept',
     '*/*',
     'Content-Length',
     '23',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/registerUser',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client:
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 183,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 3,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 222,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _server:
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idlePrev:
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000 },
     _idleStart: 144720,
     parser:
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: 17,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 17\r\nETag: W/"11-5i2g3OJs8No9M8PUhnLubxYJmZY"\r\nDate: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:06:49 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        statusMessage: 'OK',
        statusCode: 200 } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/registerUser',
  _parsedUrl:
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/registerUser',
     path: '/registerUser',
     href: '/registerUser',
     _raw: '/registerUser' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res:
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedHeader: { 'content-length': false },
     _contentLength: 17,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 222,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 144720,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 222,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 144720,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _header: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 17\r\nETag: W/"11-5i2g3OJs8No9M8PUhnLubxYJmZY"\r\nDate: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 00:06:49 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
     _headers:
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': '17',
        etag: 'W/"11-5i2g3OJs8No9M8PUhnLubxYJmZY"' },
     _headerNames:
      { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By',
        'content-type': 'Content-Type',
        'content-length': 'Content-Length',
        etag: 'ETag' },
     _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {},
     statusMessage: 'OK',
     statusCode: 200 },
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/registerUser',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
```

The question is where are my `username==test` and `foo=bar` gone? How do I access `req.data` or something like that?

I'm looking at the documentation right now: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage and it makes no sense, there's no single word about data I'm passing in my request and everything I care about is my data, that's what I'm working on, that's what I want to push to the MongoDB.

I'm missing something big. Help? :)

Comment: Keep reading that page. When you get to _"message.url"_, pay extra attention. There is a full, detailed explanation, and an example of precisely what you're trying to do...

Comment: and one thing i forget to mention @Wordpressor once you got body just push to db with by using req.body.email or whatever name is

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028851/pushing-an-object-to-an-array-in-mongodb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you working with express then the simple request will not provide your desired data if you print the request.

> req.body
>   Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).

This is what mention in documentation and recommended by Express Framework https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

so if you want to inspect it in express do some thing like this

```
var app = 

require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/registerUser', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body); //console.log(req)
  res.json(req.body); //res.send("hello world post")
});
```

You can also inspect your request with out using express framework or body parser.
here i am posting just simple example to print post body on every  request

```
var http =

 require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
     request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        var bodydata = chunk.toString('utf8');
        console.log(bodydata)
    });
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('hi welcome\n');
}).listen(8081);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

this is how will look if you use bodyparser and express

here is body is you use body parser and express

[image]

[image]

Here is my post request

[image]

here is my output converting buffer into string

[image]

here is my simple node request with out using express which contain data event

[image]

data as buffer in req

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is basically how Express works:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
  // GET /foo?msg=hello ---> {msg: 'hello'}
  console.log(req.query);
});

app.post('/bar', function (req, res) {
  // POST msg=hello ---> {msg: 'hello'}
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming request is a `GET` then you can have access to it via `req.query`, and this comes with express out of the box. If the incoming request is a `POST`, you need to use something like [this](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) and then you can have access to the incoming info with by accessing `req.body`.